# Trying to python deploy.py on Terminal: ImportError: No module named Solcx

Tags: python, json, deployment, solidity

So for the last 4 hourse I've been trying solve this. Please help
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uahKa.png)

Comment: Please do not post image of code...

Comment: Did you install that module?  If so, what exact command did you use?